# ¿cómo imprimir un vector de una columna con los datos de dos campos en php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

he estado tratando de imprimir una consulta, donde consulto dos campos, pero quiero imprimirlos en una sola variable, es decir en un vector de una columna, tengo  los  campos **nombre** , **tel** en mi base de datos y quiero que se imprima según la cantidad de registros así:

nombre

tel

nombre

tel

nombre

tel 

uno debajo del otro

```html
{
    
   
              while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
               // $id = $row['id'];
      //$var = $row["nombre"]." ".$row["tel"];
      $tel = $row['tel'];
      $nombre = $row['nombre'];
      
      
      $column = array($nombre,$tel);
   for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
      $arrlength = count($column[$x]);
     
      }
     
     
     
?> 
    <option value='<?php echo $column[$x]; ?>' required > <?php echo $column[$x] ; ?>  </option>
    
   <?php  
    }
```

Comment: Si la consulta funciona adecuadamente: `$nombre = $row['nombre']; $tel = $row['tel'];` y luego: **`echo $nombre."<br />".$tel."<br /><br />";`**

Answer (score 1):

Bastaría con hacer:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $tel = $row['tel'];
  $nombre = $row['nombre'];
  echo '<option value="'.$tel.'" required >'.$nombre.'</option>';
}
```

Pero no tiene sentido ponerle "required" a un elemento option y, además,  según tu descripción, no quieres imprimir elementos `option` sino sólo los textos. En ese caso sería

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $tel = $row['tel'];
  $nombre = $row['nombre'];
  echo $nombre.'<br>';
  echo $tel.'<br>';
}
```